# Errors trying to recompile third party library with /MT instead of /MD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

I have a project which has various third party library dependencies, some of which are built with /MD and some with /MT (which therefore can't be mixed). In order to resolve this I'm trying to recompile one of the libraries (FLTK) using /MT. However I am getting link errors such as the following, on a few of the projects within the FLTK:

```
1>fltkd.lib(fl_call_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc
1>fltkd.lib(fl_call_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv
1>fltkd.lib(fl_call_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___wargv
```

Is there anything I can do about this or does it mean the library's code is written in a way that static runtime linking is not possible?

EDIT:

The code for the object file in the above example is:

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(FL_DLL) && !defined (__GNUC__)

#  include <windows.h>
#  include <stdio.h>
#  include <stdlib.h>
#  include <FL/fl_utf8.h>

extern int main(int, char *[]);

#  ifdef BORLAND5
#    define __argc _argc
#    define __argv _argv
#  endif /* BORLAND5 */

static int mbcs2utf(const char *s, int l, char *dst)
{
  static xchar *mbwbuf;
  unsigned dstlen = 0;
  if (!s) return 0;
  dstlen = (l * 6) + 6;
  mbwbuf = (xchar*)malloc(dstlen * sizeof(xchar));
  l = (int) mbstowcs(mbwbuf, s, l);
  l = fl_utf8fromwc(dst, dstlen, mbwbuf, l);
  dst[l] = 0;
  free(mbwbuf);
  return l;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                             LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  int rc, i;
  char **ar;

#  ifdef _DEBUG

  AllocConsole();
  freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
  freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
  freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
#  endif

  ar = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (__argc + 1));
  i = 0;
  while (i < __argc) {
    int l;
    unsigned dstlen;
    if (__wargv ) {
      for (l = 0; __wargv[i] && __wargv[i][l]; l++) {}; /* is this just wstrlen??? */
      dstlen = (l * 5) + 1;
      ar[i] = (char*) malloc(dstlen);
/*    ar[i][fl_unicode2utf(__wargv[i], l, ar[i])] = 0; */
      dstlen = fl_utf8fromwc(ar[i], dstlen, __wargv[i], l);
      ar[i][dstlen] = 0;
    } else {
      for (l = 0; __argv[i] && __argv[i][l]; l++) {};
      dstlen = (l * 5) + 1;
      ar[i] = (char*) malloc(dstlen);
/*      ar[i][mbcs2utf(__argv[i], l, ar[i], dstlen)] = 0; */
      ar[i][mbcs2utf(__argv[i], l, ar[i])] = 0;
    }
    i++;
  }
  ar[__argc] = 0;
  /* Run the standard main entry point function... */
  rc = main(__argc, ar);

#  ifdef _DEBUG
  fclose(stdin);
  fclose(stdout);
  fclose(stderr);
#  endif /* _DEBUG */

  return rc;
}

#elif defined(__hpux)
/* This code to prevent "empty translation unit" or similar warnings... */
static void dummy(void) {}
#endif /* WIN32 && !FL_DLL && !__GNUC__ */
```

Comment: it looks like you flipped the flag and posted the error here. A better approach would be to take a look at what exactly this error relates to in code, see if you can address it or then ask for opinions on how to address it here.

Comment: You don't get that error from building a library, it doesn't get linked and this is a linker error.  These symbols only appear in code that was built with /MT and will fail to resolve if you link with the /MD version of the CRT, msvcrt.lib instead of libcmt.lib.  So it certainly looks like you rebuilt fltkd.lib with /MT correctly but the project that uses it isn't setup right.

Comment: @Hans I'm getting the error when I try to rebuild FLTK, not within my own project. I've edited my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: As I said, you cannot get this error when you build a library, only an executable. An EXE or DLL.  A LIB is created by lib.exe, not the linker, it is just a bag of .obj files that don't get linked until later.  Sounds like project implosion.  If a DLL is actually intended then you certainly don't want to compile with /MT.

Comment: If you look at the source for fl_call_main.obj (presumably named fl_call_main.cpp), then you might be able to find the lines of code trying to make use of those undefined symbols. My psychic powers tell me that it's trying to access the global C variables that are ordinarily passed to your "main".

Comment: @hans I was using the word library in that context to refer to FLTK as a library, not in the sense of a .lib. Some of the projects within FLTK are .lib and some are .exe and yes, the problem is occuring in the executable ones.

Comment: @selbie I've been looking at that and have a related question - the error output refers to e.g. `___argc` (with three underscores) but I can only find `__argc` in the code (two underscores). What is the meaning of the extra underscore in the error output?

Comment: I forget the rules, but leading underscores often get inserted into symbols. Can you post the code that refers to those unresolved symbols?